How to convert a Blazor server website into an app?
I currently have a Blazor server side website. It is all set up with a mobile view. I want to take this mobile view and turn it into an app that can be installed on Android and iOS. How do I do that?

using a webview which loads the website

How do I do that?

You could create a .NET MAUI Blazor Hybrid App.This app allows you to use blazor components and register services similarly. It can be build for all platforms. As you convert from a "server app" to "client app", there will be some codes you need to fix after migration.
 
Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/tutorials/maui-blazor-web-app?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Thanks. How do I do the migration?

You could just migrate all the components to this MAUI Blazor hybrid app. The program.cs services could be used similarly.
